# How to find all mutually exclusive nearest neighbours between two arrays

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have two sorted arrays of numbers. The first array is a set of n integers which are targets equally spaced between the bounds of the array. The second array has a large multiple of n integers and is also a set. I want to find the n integers from the second array which are closest to all targets in the first array, with the condition that only one integer from the second array can match any target from the first array. That is, all matches are mutually exclusive.

Thanks for any help!

Edit:

Sorry for lack of detail. This is a simplification of the real problem.

Simple first array example with regular targets: [0x0,0x7FFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF]

The second array is essentially random data without duplicates, uniformly distributed across the extents of the first array. That is, there might be 2000 integers between 0x0 and 0xFFFFFFFF. I need the three integers from the second array which are closest to the targets in the first array. In the real problem the targets will have smaller extents and more targets, always regularly spaced.

Edit: More context.

A large array B is a stream of random 32 byte hashes which have been sorted and are being fitted into a n-ary tree. For each node there are known limits u and v. Array A is constructed by dividing u and v into n-1 strides. For each subset of B which is between u and v, try and find the member of B which is closest to one of n-1 strides. These selected members are then used to further filter B for each child node below. It's basically heuristics for balancing a tree containing random data. Deep nodes have a progressively smaller B to consider. A is always fixed length.

Comment: I don't think that's clear enough. Can you give an example of the arrays, and what the correct answer should be?

Comment: do you want the common elements? or the nearly equivalent elements like for the example above do you want to find the elements that are closest to 0x0, 0x7FFFFFFF and the 0xFFFFFFFF?
Please provide the details

Comment: I want the closest integers from the second array. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search#All_nearest_neighbors

Comment: Is the second array sorted ?

Comment: "I have two sorted arrays of numbers" :-)

Answer (score 1):

First let me attempt to specify the problem formally. Call the first set of numbers A and the second set B. We want an injective map f : A -> B (injective means x != y implies f(x) != f(y)) minimizing some objective function that measures for all x how close f(x) is to x. There are multiple reasonable choices, so I'll select one for you: let's minimize sum_{x in A} |f(x) - x|. (The rest of this answer is somewhat independent of the exact objective, so long as some optimum f is an increasing function.)

The greedy algorithm (define, for all x in A, the value f(x) to be the y in B minimizing |x - y|) fails because its chosen f may not be injective. The usual repair technique is dynamic programming, which works but requires quadratic instead of linear time. Here's an untested Python sample that is supposed to compute the optimal objective value. The value of `table[(i, j)]` is the optimum cost of mapping the first `i` elements of `A` into the first `j` elements of `B`.

```
def assign(A, B):
    m = len(A)
    n = len(B)
    table = {(0, j): 0 for j in range(n + 1)}
    for i in range(1, m + 1):
        table[(i, 0)] = 1e309  # infinity
        for j in range(1, n + 1):
            table[(i, j)] = min(table[(i - 1, j - 1)] + abs(A[i - 1] - B[j - 1]),
                                table[(i, j - 1)])
    return table[(m, n)]
```

To recover the matching at the end, we extend the code to make another entry in each table indicating which branch of the min was taken, then trace the decisions back to a `(0, j)` entry.

Now, I don't know how big your problem is, nor how fast you want the results, but let's suppose that quadratic time is unacceptable for whatever reason. The code above, in general, considers a lot of obviously silly matches between elements that are far from each other. Below I'll make "obviously silly" a technical term, with an effective definition and a linear-time algorithm. Then we can replace the range of `j` considered in the inner loop with something a lot smaller, hopefully linear-size on average because B is much denser than A and semi-reasonably distributed. The running time decreases correspondingly.

Observe that it makes no sense to match the minimum x in A to anything larger than min {y : y in B, y >= x}, which I'll call the upper neighbor of x. If we did, and f were increasing, then we could change f(x) to x's upper neighbor and improve the objective value without a constraint violation. If we greedily assign each element x' in A from least to greatest the lowest available y' in B not less than x', then we can show by induction that there exists an optimal solution where each x' is matched to a value no greater than its y'. Moreover, we can compute these values in linear time as follows (more untested Python).

```
def uppers(A, B):
    n = len(B)
    j = 0
    for x in A:
        while j < n and B[j] < x:
            j += 1
        if j < n:
            j += 1
        yield j  # exclusive upper bound
```

Symmetrically, we can compute lower bounds. Call any assignment outside of these bounds "obviously silly" and proceed as described previously.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I will test the equivalent code in Go and report back any results. A bit more

Comment: @Donny `uppers` was buggy. I attempted to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your arrays are `a` (with `m` integers) and `b` (with `n` integers).

Since both arrays are sorted, then (if I've understood the problem correctly) for each value in `a`, `x` will be the value in `b` closest to `a[i]`:

```
x = b[a[i] * (n-1) / (a[m-1] - a[0])]
```

Comment: This depends on the random numbers demonstrating an absolutely uniform distribution, which is unlikely.

Comment: Yes, I was assuming that they would be since the question stated that the numbers in b were "uniformly distributed across the extents of the first array".

Comment: The keyword is absolute :-) There's likely to be sequences in a sorted random stream which don't adhere to the expected form, especially for low m and high n in your example.

Comment: In that case it seems the only sensible thing to do is to do a binary search for a[i] in b for every a[i], which will still be fast: O(m*log(n))

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't handle the condition that an integer in b might only be used once. Consider A=[0,5,10] and B=[1,2,3]. This doesn't look like a uniform B, but a random stream could contain it.

Answer (score 0):

(would-be comment:)
Thinking of the second array as b, I will refer to its element at index Ib as B. A binary search for any given target yields the closest B not above (or below); one task would be to specify which Bs constitute the three nearest neighbours; I'd suggest to consider consecutive elements adjacent to B, only (normally from Ib-2 to Ib+2). Measures to minimise would include sum of distances, their absolute values, or squares.
Another problem is two (or more) targets contending for some Bs - it should get nasty if the number of contenders can't be limited.
(Nag: wording leaves room for improvement: `the targets will have [...] more targets`)

Comment: Random data tends to highlight the pathological cases were contention for a match occurs. I guess the k in k nearest neighbours would have to be equal to the number of targets to cover all cases...

Comment: @Donny `It's basically heuristics for balancing a tree containing random data.` - from sorted data, you can construct search trees balanced to any criterion of your liking; for an n-ary tree compute the number of items per leaf, if at the end of any node there are items left, add a key and a link in the level above and continue with another node.

Comment: It's a bit more tricky than that :-) We can't do rotations. Max number of children per node is fixed. Range of a node cannot change once fixed. Think of it as more of an append only tree containing random data.

Comment: @Donny Knowing the sorted data upfront and constructing the tree balanced to begin with, there is no need to ever rebalance or rotate.

Comment: The random data comes in batches. The OP scenario is just one batch. The matching algorithm will be reused for every insertion in every node for every batch. I may be overthinking it and a much more naive implementation may actually work well with random data :-)